# Function declaration vs Function expression: what will be printed in this case?

Tags: javascript, function

I read lots of pages on this argument, but still can't understand why this (declaration)

```
function foo() {console.log("foo");}

(function(){
  // Really there is nothing here
})();
```

doesn't do anything, while this (expression)

```
var foo = function() {console.log("foo");}

(function(){
  // Really there is nothing here
})();
```

outputs

> foo
>
> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

What's going or here?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after the assignment. It should be `var foo = function() {console.log("foo");};`. I'm quite certain this is a duplicate, will try to find it...

Comment: Absolutely right. So, it's more a *Syntax Error* but the parser is not  smart enough to figure it out. Still can't understand why "foo" is printed, and what it really tries to apply

Comment: Yeah, it's a logical syntax error, but it's valid JavaScript :) (and I couldn't find a duplicate, though I'm sure I have seen this before... anyways, you got your help I guess :))

Comment: @Raffaele: The "foo" comes from `console.log("foo");` in the first function. It's called directly, not assigned to the variable. The result of the calls would be assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case why semi colons should NOT be optional. Whitespace is just there to make it easier for us to read. The code:

```
var foo = function() {console.log("foo");}

(function(){
    // Really there is nothing here
})();
```

looks like this

```
var foo = function() {console.log("foo");}(function(){})();
```

making it look like a named function call

```
myFunction(function(){})();
```

or

```
myFunction("some code")();
```

The first function `myFunction("some code")` returns undefined and than you try to run that function.

```
~undefined~();
```

So with the return in there.

```
var foo = function() {console.log("foo"); return undefined;}(function(){})();
```

The code would run fine if you returned a function

```
var foo = function() {console.log("foo"); return arguments[0];}(function(){return "hello"})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the semicolon after the assignment, as Felix Kling pointed out.

The parenthesis around the second anonymous function will be interpreted as the parentheses around the parameters for a function call:

```
var foo = function() {console.log("foo");}(function(){ })();
```

The expression `function() {console.log("foo");}(function(){ })` will return `undefined` as there is no return statement in the first function. The last pair of parentheses will make it another function call, but as `undefined` is not a function, you get that specific error message.

Comment: One of the `gotchas` of javascript